# Selenium out of stack space in IE11 (but not Chrome)

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I turned off protected mode, edited the registry, made sure zoom is at 100 but this selenium script complains with the error "Out of stack space (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)". The commented chromedriver works perfectly.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver; 
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.InternetExplorerDriverManager;


public class CssSelectors implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        InternetExplorerDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();    
        test(driver);           
    }

    public static void test (WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys("tokyo");

        }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? Can you trim away all the non-[MCVE] code?

Comment: Out of stack space (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Added that info to the question for you. Unfortunately I don't have IE11 to try this on :(

Comment: The [docs on SeleniumHQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) also mention the IEDriverServer executable that must be on your path. Is that there?

Comment: I may have found the issue.         `driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox")).sendKeys("tokyo");` does not work while         `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchbox")).sendKeys("tokyo");` does

Comment: Wow that's weird. Good to have a workaround. I suggest checking the [Selenium IE driver issue tracker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) for information about that. Incidentally, I just found [issue 1942](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1942) that might also solve your problem.